# Get Latest N numbers of records from table using where in condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, having-clause

Need to fetch the latest 3 records from tables of each `orderid(s)` related to `storeid(s)` using `WHERE IN` condition.

For Eg:

```
--------------------------
orderid      storeid
1               2
5               2
7               2
15              5
18              5
25              5
29              9
65              9
78              9
------------------------
```

Here my Query:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE store_id IN('2', '5', '9') ORDER BY store_id
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: latest means date/time-wise? or something else?

Comment: @M.Hemant `order by orderid`

Comment: so you can do that with an `order by orderid desc` so what stopping you now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the mysql solution to get `n` number of rows for each store:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
SELECT 
    store_id,
    order_id,
    @curRank := CASE WHEN @prevStore = store_id THEN @curRank + 1 ELSE 0 END AS rank,
    @prevStore:= store_id AS prevStore
FROM orders a, (SELECT @curRank := 0, @prevStore := NULL) r
WHERE store_id IN('2', '5', '9')
ORDER BY 1 desc,2
)a 

WHERE a.rank<3;
```

Answer (score 1):

using `row_number()` you can get the latest 3 `orderids`

```
select * from orders o
inner join (
   select row_number() over (partition by storeid order by orderid desc) rn, orderid 
   from orders) t1 on t1.orderid = o.orderid
where t1.rn <= 3
```

Comment: I agree with your answer, but his image seems to imply something else :-)

Comment: yes, i think so. op seems to convert this query to orm.